# How do I specify an alternative bridge interface (not br0) when using qemu-bridge-helper

Tags: linux, networking, kvm, qemu, bridge

By following the instructions found at http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/HelperNetworking I can configure qemu with qemu-bridge-helper, however, I can't figure out how to pass a bridging interface option with `-netdev`.

The source code on Github, https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/qemu-bridge-helper.c, indicates it accepts `--br` to specify it, but I can't find any documentation on how to pass that when using `-netdev`.

For reference, my current configuration which uses `br0` looks something like:
`-netdev tap,helper=/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper,id=hn0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hn0,id=nic1`.